# Splitting database throwing errno 9 bad file descriptor with CON file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've done some research and from what I can tell this normally happens when a file is closed before it's finished being used?

But that doesn't make sense for what is happening here.

Here is my code:

```
import csv

dicto = {}
name = ""

with open(input("enter filepath here: "), "r") as mainfile:
    reader = csv.reader(mainfile)
    for row in reader:
        name = row[8].lstrip("'")
        name = name.lstrip("\xa0")
        name1 = name
        name = name.upper()
        if not name[:3] in dicto:
            dicto[name[:3]] = [name[:3]+".js", 0]
            with open(dicto[name[:3]][0], "w") as file1: #here is the problem line
                file1.write("tags=[")
        else:
            dicto[name[:3]][1] += 1
        if name[:1] == "#":
            print(name)
        with open(dicto[name[:3]][0], "a") as file2:
            if dicto[name[:3]][1]>0:
                file2.write('various spam')
            else:
                file2.write('various eggs')
for key in dicto.keys():
    with open(dicto[key][0], "a") as file3:
        file3.write("\n];")
```

I'm running through a large database and splitting it up into JS files which are named after the first three letters of the data's label. It seems to run ok at first (there are 44k entries to go through so it takes a few seconds to finish). Overall I currently have 309 files generated, although none are complete. However Once it gets to the combo "CON" an error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SarbickiN\Documents\Codes\Python\schools\schools.py", line 16, in <module>
    with open(dicto[name[:3]][0], "w") as file1:
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor: 'CON.js'
```

and this shuts down the programme. Is there any reason why this would have happened? I've made a comment next to the line causing the issue.

---

### Edit: solution (or lack thereof)

`CON` is a reserved name for files in windows along with a few others so would need to be replaced with something else. [Check here for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#naming_conventions).

Comment: Is the file open somewhere? Try closing it after the `write` call.

Comment: It doesn't exist at the moment, Python is generating new files each time it encounters a new combination, the only original files in the folder are my database.csv and database.py.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), accept your answer to mark this question as closed. In your answer, you can refer to [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#naming_conventions) which details all the reserved words in Windows that cannot be used as filenames.

Comment: I was looking for that button in edit but couldn't find it.

Comment: @Scironic just use the answer box below.

Comment: Done. I'll accept in a couple days. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Self answering

CON is a reserved name for files in windows along with a few others so would need to be replaced with something else. [Check here for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#naming_conventions).